# Google Chrome: How can I keep an element's z-index after its position is dynamically set to 'fixed'?

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome

Okay, what's most annoying about this is it was working with google Chrome a week ago then suddenly it just stopped working.

Here's my problem:  I have some absolutely positioned divs that change to fixed position after scrolling past a certain point.  That part works fine, but I have some z-indexes set on elements inside those divs that get overridden when the position changes to fixed.

[see the problem](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i67lj544fikdo1e/compare.jpg)

html:

```
   <div id="leftSide">
        <div id="leftSideBottom"></div>

        <div id="leftSideTop">

            <div id="nav">
                <a href="#home" class="home"></a>
                <a href="#about" class="about"></a>
                <a href="#work" class="work"></a>
                <a href="#blog" class="blog"></a>
                <a href="#connect" class="connect"></a>
            </div>

        </div> <!-- end leftSideTop -->

    </div> <!-- end leftSide -->

    <div id="rightSide">

        <div id="rightSideBottom"></div>

        <div id="rightSideTop">

        </div> <!-- end rightSideTop -->

    </div> <!-- end rightSide -->
```

css:

```
   #leftSide {
       position: absolute;
       margin-top: 160px;
       top: 0;
       left: -20px;
   }

   #rightSide {
       position: absolute;
       margin-top: 160px;
       top: 0;
       left: 880px; // ie breaks if I use right: -20px
   }

   #rightSideTop, #leftSideTop {
       position: absolute;
       width: 100px;
       height: 600px;
   }

   #rightSideBottom, #leftSideBottom {
       position: absolute;
       width: 40px;
       height: 600px;
       right: 0; // leftSideBottom will have this set to left: 0, just combine code to simplify
       top: 0;
       z-index: -100;
   }

   .fixed {
       position: fixed;
       top: 150px;
   }
```

jQuery:

```
    var aboutTop = $("#about").offset().top;
    var connectTop = $("#connect").offset().top;

    $(window).scroll(function(){
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if(y >= aboutTop && y < connectTop){
        $("#greenSideLeftTop,#greenSideLeftBottom").addClass("fixed");
        $("#greenSideRightTop,#greenSideRightBottom").addClass("fixed");
    }
    else if(y >= connectTop){
        $("#greenSideLeftTop,#greenSideLeftBottom").removeClass("fixed");
        $("#greenSideRightTop,#greenSideRightBottom").removeClass("fixed");
        $("#leftSide").css("top",connectTop - 1080);
        $("#rightSide").css("top",connectTop - 1080);
    }

    else{
        $("#greenSideLeftTop,#greenSideLeftBottom").removeClass("fixed");
        $("#greenSideRightTop,#greenSideRightBottom").removeClass("fixed");
        $("#leftSide").css("top",aboutTop - 1080);
        $("#rightSide").css("top",aboutTop - 1080);
    }
});
```

If my problem still sounds confusing check it out for yourself: [my website's problem](http://jakezeitz.99k.org/New%20Design/index.html).  Use chrome and scroll down, it works in firefox and ie.

I gotta make this work cross-browser somehow... can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome has recently changed the method of rendering fixed position items. Use jQuery `.css` to  set the zindex instead.

Comment: I tried `$("#greenSideLeftBottom").css("z-index",-100);` but it still produces the same result.  In what way has chrome changed the way it renders fixed position?

Comment: This worked but its ugly. I had to set and reset a lot of css attributes for each scroll event. Anyway, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome is moving the inner div into the same layer when the outer div is `position: fixed`.

The simplest fix I can come up with is to separate the two divs (greenSide...Top and greenSide...Bottom) instead of nesting and position them separately.

```
<div id="rightSide">
    <div id="greenSideRightTop"></div>
    <div id="greenSideRightBottom"></div>
</div> <!-- end rightSide -->
```

Comment: I un-nested the divs, but now I'm having trouble getting the greenSide..Bottom to receive the class 'fixed' in my jQuery. I tried adding it to the selector: $("#greenSideLeftTop, #greenSideLeftBottom").addClass("fixed"); and I tried splitting it up but I can't get it to respond